# Find SAP modifications of function groups includes

Tags: abap, sap-basis

(access key for SAP standard modifications needed for test data of this question)

**Introduction**:
I want to find a certain type of modification to a certain SAP standard repository object (IDES test dataset). 
The modification is located in the include of a function group (it is listed under System-defined Include-files in the functionpool of the function group).
So far, I found the table SMODILOG as a central list of modifications (Log of Customer Modifications to Dev. Env. Objects).

**Test Data**:
My test data is function group V07A, that has e.g. the include LV07A014 (Part of the LV07ANNN include). This was modified by inserting stuff in its source code (one needs an access key in order to be allowed to do this) such as:

```
*{   INSERT         IDSEXAMPLE                                        1
* this is a comment, which was added
*}   INSERT
```

**Goal**:
Subsequently I want to find a table where all modifications like this are listed. I want to find the place of modification, i.e. the object type and program id of the object that was modified.

---

**2 Questions**:
I realize that the SAP standard include of a function group has a different object type and program ID than the top-include and uxx-includes.
Whereas the latter are of type PROG and prgmid R3TR (found in object catalog entry), the LV07A014 has an object catalog entry identical to the function group that it belongs to, namely R3TR FUGR. This is already peculiar to me. This seems to me as if the resolution to the sub-level (include level) is missing.

In addition, the modification to LV07A014 is listed in table SMODILOG as having the object type (field sub_type) REPS (the pgmid is not included in SMODILOG). I would expect PROG, as for the other inclueds (LTOP, LUXX).

-> Why is there a difference of object types, programids between L_TOP, L_UXX on the one hand and L_NNN Inclues on the other? (Or am I mistaken?)

-> Where can I find information of all SAP standard modifications in my system and the true object type,pgmid belonging to these modified objects (and not the function group that the modified object belongs to, this resolution does not suffice)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no table or something similar where all modifications are listed. The table E071 is a good source to check pgmid and object type.

Why there is a difference of object types, program IDs between L_TOP, L_UXX on the one hand and L_NNN Includes on the other remains a mystery. SAP...

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a table? For what? Is it purely academic question or connected with real life tasks?

Have you ever tried SE95 transaction? It lists **all** modifications that were done in system disregard of object type and name. Yes, and function groups too. They are easily searchable by hierarchy

If it is FUGR include that was modified, then it will be listed in the node **Outside of modularization units**

[image]

Finally [RTFM](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d31c01d526747e898a6073fba44674f/7.4.19/en-US/60d6ba75ceda11d1953a0000e82de14a.html), bro...

Comment: I need a table, because I don't want to do it manually. But I should investigate this transaction I was not aware of that.